# I am getting error "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: eclipse, testing, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette

I am using selenium Webdriver for the testing web application. I am using marioette driver for the same as I am havin firefox 48.0 since yusing the same the web page gets open however I am not able to put the values in the text box it gives the error " java.lang.NullPointerException"
I have written code

```js
@BeforeTest
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\ashwini\\geckodriver.exe");

          driver= new MarionetteDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }

@Test
      public void testAddAccount() throws Exception {
        driver.get("http://qa.luna.wexeurope.com/CPCardWeb/login.htm?programme=CPYCGB");

        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("cp_admin");
}


@AfterTest
      public void teardown()
      {
          driver.quit();
      }
```

Output is:

```
1472448949884   Marionette  INFO    sendAsync 3744f8a9-772e-42fe-8c85-6f9964888fb1
FAILED: testAddAccount
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Add_Account.testAddAccount(Add_Account.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I have checked the same it gives null values in sendkeys.
However instead of by.id I have used other options like name, xpath, css selector for the same
it gives the error only.
 Value is still not inserted in the text box

Line no 36 is
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("cp_admin");

I have debug that as you said, Yes it passes the  null value to the element that's why it throws null pointer exception. so please let me know to solve this. as I have tried to pass values using the id, name, xpath, css selecter. same error is displayed. so could u please help me?

Comment: put a debug point and check whether the element gets  identified " driver.findElement(By.id("username"))", it might be coming null and in next line when you try to send keys , statement goes like null.sendKeys which throws null pointer exception

Comment: I have debug that as you said, Yes it passes the null value to the element that's why it throws null pointer exception. so please let me know to solve this. as I have tried to pass values using the id, name, xpath, css selecter. same error is displayed. so could u please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue is resolved by removing unwanted jar from the referenced library

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` means your driver is not initialized properly and hence it has null value when it tries to find a element. This is not related to xpath/id etc.

Please check line number 36 of Add_Account class you will get to know where exactly there is  an error. It will be good if you put whole code of your class for anyone to look into.